# Angular 5 Material datatable 'this.dataSource.connect is not a function'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-datatables

I am stuck in this issue since last 2 days. I am trying to fetch the json data from my json file into material 5 datatable. company is my interface. Using a service to get the data which returns an object. I am getting the data in MatTableDataSource. However it's not getting printed in the table. I passed the array in MatTableDataSource. But still no use. Please help!

```
        import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
         // import { DataTableDataSource } from './data-table-datasource';

        import { RecordsService } from '../../services/records.service';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
        import { MatSort, MatSortable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

        import { Company } from '../../models/classes/company';


        @Component({
          selector: 'data-table',
          templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
        })
        export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
          records: Array<any>;
          dataSource;
          displayedColumns = ['accountId', 'currency']; // , 'Account Number', 'Sort Code', 'Price'

          constructor(private recService: RecordsService) {}
          ngOnInit() {
            this.recService.getResults().subscribe( results => {
              // if (!results) {
              //   return;
              // }
              let ds = new MatTableDataSource(results);
              this.dataSource = ds.data;
              console.log(this.dataSource);
            });
          }
        }

    //HTML

    <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource?.content">

        <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="accountId">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>AccountId</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let record">{{record.accountId}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="currency">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Currency</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let record">{{record.currency}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" color="primary"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>


    </div>
```

Below is my service file:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    import { Company } from '../models/classes/company';

    @Injectable()
    export class RecordsService {
      private record: Company[];
      private dataURL = '../../assets/data/results.json';
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getResults(): Observable<Company[]> {
       return this.http.get<Company[]>(this.dataURL);
       }
    }


My error is below:
ERROR TypeError: this.dataSource.connect is not a function
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? `this.dataSource = ds.data;`, try just with `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);`

Comment: and after that in the template use `[dataSource]="dataSource"` instead of `[dataSource]="dataSource?.content"`

Comment: I already tried 'this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);' It gave me the issue that the expected format of the data to iterate in the for loop is an array. I tried to pass my data in the array format still it didn't work.

Comment: @izmaylovdev : [dataSource]="dataSource" trying this didn't help.

Comment: what error did you get when you tried this?
`this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);`
`[dataSource]="dataSource"`

Comment: DataTableComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: `results` it'a array? If not you need use `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([results])`

Comment: you can use the `.map` operator in your service to return the `result` in the desired format.

Comment: this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([results]); doesn't give me an error but doesn't show any data either.

Comment: One thing is that the my above code worked on my friend's windows laptop, but the same code didn't work on the mac system of mine and one other mac.

Comment: @ Diego Cardozo : it worked 'return this.http.get<Company[]>(this.dataURL).map((res: any) => res.content); '  Thanks.